# Ice Cream buckets

Tags: piece-information, design

I'm trying to plan an ice cream shop. For the ice cream itself, I'm considering using the [1 x 1 buckets](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=95343#T=S&O=%7B%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D). Does a 1 x 1 round tile snap into one of those?  If not, can someone recommend a way to do buckets of ice cream?

Comment: Sounds like a cool idea. You also might want to consider using part number 11610 in tan as the cones with part number 15470 on top, I saw this method in an Angry Birds set and it looked very nice.

Answer (score 9):

Yes it fits in, here are a few official sets that do exactly that

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60133-23
[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=coltlbm2-14
[image]